# Desktop crashes after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 "Connection to xwayland lost"

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, wayland

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS to 20.04 and since then my display appears to crash periodically, say every 15-30 minutes. I found this error in syslog:

```
Connection to xwayland lost
gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1025
```

The same error appears with every crash. The screen becomes unresponsive and I have to hard reboot. I have tried several different frontends with the same result. Also tried reinstalling gnome-shell and disabling all extensions (there were only 3).

Lenovo-Yoga-500-15ISK
Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 
Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)
64-bit

Comment: It looks like an issue with the display server (Wayland/ X server compatibility layer).

When you say you've tried installing different front ends- are we talking desktop environments?

Comment: Yes so I tried Unity, Gnome classic, Ubuntu-wayland and the standard Ubuntu with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer was a required BIOS upgrade for the Lenovo Yoga - D3CN39WW    from Sept 2018. FreeDOS would not work as this BIOS requires a Win32 environment to be run. Install old Windows laptop hard drive and run.

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/et/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-500-15isk